# where to observe the global data structures, variables in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

Wehn I debug and reach a breakpoint I can see only the local variables in the Locals tab in visual studio 2008.

where to observe the global data structures, variables in visual studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `Watch` window. The `Local` tab is for local variables, as the name clearly suggests.

You'll need to add the variable manually. You can go to the quick-watch window - `Ctrl + Alt + Q`, enter the variable name there, and press `Add Watch`. The variable will be added to the Watch window.

Comment: or you can go directly to watch window: Debug->windows->watch->watch1/watch2/watch3/watch4  or via CTRl+ALT+W and the number of watch window (1 to 4)

Answer (score 2):

`Watch` is obviously the best way to do it, but there is also useful window `Autos`, which automatically shows variables depending on context (e.g. what is used in current line).

You can turn it on during debugging `Debug -> Windows -> Autos` (`CTRL + D, A`).

Comment: im trying to add a global variable in watch, but it says identifier "GLOBAL_VARIABLE_NAME" is undefined, anyone know why?

Comment: oh nvm turns out its because they are in a diffrent namespace

Comment: how about constants in other headers? the headers don't have separate namespace and is already included but still not able to show it in watch window. It only says "the symbol is not allowed". I ended up, opening the other file constant which is an array of struct and check which index i'm already in. Is there a way to make this work?